# how can I preload/defer javascript in a similar way to css

Tags: javascript, preload, deferred-loading

I'm using this to preload/ defer css but is there a way to also do similar with javascipt files, I've looked everywhere I can think of but not found it, maybe I'm doing the wrong searches:

```
<link rel="preload" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/8.2.0/video-js.min.css" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'"
    integrity="sha512-akMT+LKE5CNd8NbHp0x0u6CoUJDZSMBFd5iunyEJReywcV9G10IJdNyCgxK+pnhDpnqsaPQsO3x7mnZZAs0CUA=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    >
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/8.2.0/video-js.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-akMT+LKE5CNd8NbHp0x0u6CoUJDZSMBFd5iunyEJReywcV9G10IJdNyCgxK+pnhDpnqsaPQsO3x7mnZZAs0CUA=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></noscript>
```

Comment: You should be able to preload js files by setting `<link rel="preload" as="script" href="critical.js">`

Comment: thats doesnt work for me, as ai get a "blank" screen then, its loading videojs and this warning pops up: The resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

Comment: It tells you that you are not using the preloaded script, try to look at this [google developers article](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/link-rel-preload/) and see if that solves your problem. You need to create a script tag afterwards and use the preloaded resource.